# Show Kindle books in iPhone spotlight search

Tags: iphone, spotlight, ebook, kindle

Is it possible to search for specific Kindle books in iPhone spotlight search. For example say I have To Kill a Mockingbird ebook in Kindle. Can I search for ‘To Kill a Mockingbird’ in spotlight search?